# Stop animation from looping with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

What I want to happen is when I hover the cursor to an image, it will start the looping animation. And when I leave the cursor, it stops the animation. It indeed stops but the looping animation does not work anymore when I hover it to a image again.

```
$(".right-section img").mouseenter(function() {

  var hoveredImage = $(this).attr("id");

  function loop() {

    $("#" + hoveredImage).animate({
      bottom: "15px"
    }, 500).animate({
      bottom: 0
    }, 500, function() {
      loop();
    });
  }

  loop();

  $("#" + hoveredImage).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).dequeue();
    $(this).css({
      bottom: ""
    });
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you require call `stop()` to clear the animation queue for the `img`:

```js
$(".right-section img").mouseenter(function() {
  function loop($img) {
    $img.animate({
      bottom: "15px"
    }, 500).animate({
      bottom: 0
    }, 500, function() {
      loop($img);
    });
  }

  loop($(this));
}).mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).stop(true);
});
```

```css
.right-section img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #C00;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="right-section">
  <img />
</div>
```

That being said, a far better approach would be to use CSS for the animation. CSS performs better, and also it better meets the separation of concerns principle. Try this:

```css
.right-section img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #C00;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.right-section img:hover {
  animation: bounce 1s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0% { bottom: 0; }
  50% { bottom: 15px; }
  100% { bottom: 0; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="right-section">
  <img />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I have a question, is it better to rely more on CSS in practice when I want to do an animation for a element rather than using javascript?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. The performance of CSS animation is orders of magnitude better than jQuery, or even plain JS.